# Rails: How should I adjust the 'each' method under a nest structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Before putting `pin`under the nest structure of `group`,

One of the view looked like this:

```
 <div class="transitions-enabled" id="pins">

<% @pins.each do |pin| %>
    <div class="box panel panel-default">
        <%= link_to (image_tag pin.image.url), pin %>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <h2><%= link_to pin.title, pin %></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="row footer-all">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p class="user">Submitted by <%= pin.user.username %></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="btn-group like_btn">
                        <% if user_signed_in? %>
                            <% if current_user.voted_up_on?(pin) %>
                                <%= link_to unlike_pin_path(pin), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
                                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></span>
                                <%= pin.get_upvotes.size %>
                                <%end%>
                            <% else %>
                                <%= link_to like_pin_path(pin), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
                                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></span>
                                <%= pin.get_upvotes.size %>
                                <%end%>
                            <% end %>   
                        <% else %>
                            <div class="like_btn">
                                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></span>
                                <%= pin.get_upvotes.size %>
                            </div>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
<%end%>
```

How should I adjust it after I put it under `group` (I'll mark the code which I think needed to change with'*  *'):

Group has_many pins

Pin belongs_to group

```
 <div class="transitions-enabled" id="pins">

<% @pins.each do |pin| %>
    <div class="box panel panel-default">
        <%= link_to (image_tag pin.image.url), *pin* %>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <h2><%= link_to pin.title, *pin* %></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="row footer-all">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p class="user">Submitted by <%= pin.user.username %></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="btn-group like_btn">
                        <% if user_signed_in? %>
                            <% if current_user.voted_up_on?(*pin*) %>
                                <%= link_to unlike_group_pin_path(*pin*), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
                                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></span>
                                <%= pin.get_upvotes.size %>
                                <%end%>
                            <% else %>
                                <%= link_to like_group_pin_path(*pin*), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
                                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></span>
                                <%= pin.get_upvotes.size %>
                                <%end%>
                            <% end %>   
                        <% else %>
                            <div class="like_btn">
                                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></span>
                                <%= pin.get_upvotes.size %>
                            </div>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
<%end%>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "How should I adjust it after I put it under group (I'll '* *' the code where I think should be changed)"?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. I meant: Group has_many pins; Pin belongs_to group. It seems that there are some parts to be changed in the code.

Comment: OP meant that, the code has been marked between two asteriks where OP felt the code should be changed.

Comment: Yes, thank you @VamsiKrishna for explaining for me. Forgive me for the poor grammar.

Comment: This is a view page of pin right? I think only unlike_group_pin_path and like_group_pin_path alone should be changed to pin.group. Every where else it would be pin.

Comment: After adding a relationship: Pin belongs_to Group, did you change anything in your controller for this view? My guess is that you wanted the pins shown on that page to be filtered accordingly depending on the group? so for example, sometimes this view file will show pins belonging to group A, but sometimes this view file will render pins belonging to group B.

Comment: Can you be more clear on what you need to view in the second part? I felt you just need like and unlike for group. But, @Jay-ArPolidario felt something else which is quite valid.

Comment: I let the 'show' method in group_controller to redirect_into group_pins_path, which is the view I'm showing in the question.
I have many pins in a group and I have many groups, so @Jay-ArPolidario is completely right. The first file I'm showing is the version in which there's no 'Group' yet.

Comment: https://github.com/kpfzboekbof/Pinterest_like_voting_system
My repository.

Comment: When I state this: <%= link_to (image_tag pin.image.url), pin %>, it'll appear 'undefined method `pin_path'

Answer (score 0):

After stating that your objective is to use this view file to filter the pins depending on its group, then I can think of two approaches for this.

1. Use nested resources. [(RailsCast)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources)

   - This is a little trickier than 2. but it is much more organised, and RESTful
   - You could  check the RailsCast if you are interested. Otherwise, I will just go explaining 2. as it's simpler.
2. Use params[:group_id] to filter the pins.

In the PinsController, add the following at the very end of the method where this view is rendered.

```
@group = Group.where(id: params[:group_id]).first
@pins = @pins.where(group: @group) if @group
```

Then in your view files, you'll just have to tweak your links to specify the group_id parameter. If this view file is associated to the #index method, then change

```
<%= link_to 'Link', pins_path %>
```

Into

```
<%= link_to 'Link', pins_path(group_id: 1) %>
```

Change 1 accordingly as you wish. If you don't specify the parameter group_id, the link will still work but you will notice that the page will show all pins, and not filtered by group.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help, I think I find the problem:

The view should be changed into:

```
 <div class="transitions-enabled" id="pins">

<% @pins.each do |pin| %>
    <div class="box panel panel-default">
        <%= link_to (image_tag pin.image.url), group_pin_path(@group, pin)
         %>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <h2><%= link_to pin.title, group_pin_path(@group, pin) %></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="row footer-all">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p class="user">Submitted by <%= pin.user.username %></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="btn-group like_btn">
                        <% if user_signed_in? %>
                            <% if current_user.voted_up_on?(@group, pin) %>
                                <%= link_to unlike_group_pin_path(@group, pin), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
                                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></span>
                                <%= pin.get_upvotes.size %>
                                <%end%>
                            <% else %>
                                <%= link_to like_group_pin_path(@group, pin), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
                                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></span>
                                <%= pin.get_upvotes.size %>
                                <%end%>
                            <% end %>   
                        <% else %>
                            <div class="like_btn">
                                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></span>
                                <%= pin.get_upvotes.size %>
                            </div>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
<%end%>
```

And remember to state `@group = Group.find(params[:group_id])` in the PinController, this is very important.